# Need help to understand below python code

Tags: python

I am new to Python, wondering what's the difference is between the below code.

```
name = input('Enter your name:')
print('Hello,',name)



print('What is your name?')  
myName = input()
print('It is good to meet you,'myName)
```

The second piece of code throws an invalid syntax error and it needs a '+' to execute. But, I would like to know why?

```
print('It is good to meet you,'+myName)
```

Comment: Because such is the Python syntax. `'str'variable` doesn't mean anything.

Comment: btw this: `print('It is good to meet you,',myName)` will also work, just like the first `print` in your snippet.

Comment: Your first print has a comma between separate values. The one that doesn't work has omitted the comma.

Comment: This is a question about the basics of Python. Please remember that Stack Overflow can not replace actually learning a language.

Answer (score 1):

This is because your `input()` function renders your stdin as a string and in order to concatenate two strings in python, this is normally done by the + operator.

i.e.

```py
name = "Jane"
greeting = "Hello"

concatenate = name + " " + greeting

print(concatenate)
# Hello Jane
```